# Trouble Compiling Rcpp

Tags: c++, linux, r, gcc, centos

I'm having some trouble installing Rcpp for R 3.2.2 on a CentOS 6.5 box. I've found answers that didn't really help both here on StackOverflow and other forums that don't seem to offer much in terms of a solution to this problem. If I attempt to install from within R or from command line with `R CMD INSTALL` I'm greeted by similar errors ultimately that Rcpp couldn't be installed with the final error `make: *** [Date.o] Error 1`  and the line/error previous to that being `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/exception:35: error: expected declaration before end of line`.

Below is my attempt at installing via `R CMD INSTALL Rcpp_0.12.1.tar.gz` after grabbing the tarball from https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/.

```
$ sudo R CMD INSTALL Rcpp_0.12.1.tar.gz
* installing to library ‘/usr/lib64/R/library’
* installing *source* package ‘Rcpp’ ...
** package ‘Rcpp’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs
g++ -m64 -I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include/ -I/usr/local/include    -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic  -c Date.cpp -o Date.o
In file included from ../inst/include/Rcpp/platform/compiler.h:100,
                 from ../inst/include/Rcpp/r/headers.h:48,
                 from ../inst/include/RcppCommon.h:29,
                 from ../inst/include/Rcpp.h:27,
                 from Date.cpp:31:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/cmath:43:28: error: bits/c++config.h: No such file or directory
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_tree.h:63,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/map:60,
                 from ../inst/include/Rcpp/platform/compiler.h:176,
                 from ../inst/include/Rcpp/r/headers.h:48,
                 from ../inst/include/RcppCommon.h:29,
                 from ../inst/include/Rcpp.h:27,
                 from Date.cpp:31:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/allocator.h:48:31: error: bits/c++allocator.h: No such file or directory
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/ios:42,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/ostream:40,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/iterator:65,
                 from ../inst/include/RcppCommon.h:49,
                 from ../inst/include/Rcpp.h:27,
                 from Date.cpp:31:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/localefwd.h:42:76: error: bits/c++locale.h: No such file or directory
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/ios:43,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/ostream:40,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/iterator:65,
                 from ../inst/include/RcppCommon.h:49,
                 from ../inst/include/Rcpp.h:27,
                 from Date.cpp:31:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/ext/atomicity.h:34:23: error: bits/gthr.h: No such file or directory
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/ext/atomicity.h:35:30: error: bits/atomic_word.h: No such file or directory
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/basic_ios.h:39,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/ios:45,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/ostream:40,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/iterator:65,
                 from ../inst/include/RcppCommon.h:49,
                 from ../inst/include/Rcpp.h:27,
                 from Date.cpp:31:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/locale_facets.h:43:30: error: bits/ctype_base.h: No such file or directory
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/locale_facets.h:1510:31: error: bits/ctype_inline.h: No such file or directory
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/cmath:44,
                 from ../inst/include/Rcpp/platform/compiler.h:100,
                 from ../inst/include/Rcpp/r/headers.h:48,
                 from ../inst/include/RcppCommon.h:29,
                 from ../inst/include/Rcpp.h:27,
                 from Date.cpp:31:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/cpp_type_traits.h:69: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘(’ token
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/cpp_type_traits.h:74: error: ‘_GLIBCXX_END_NAMESPACE’ does not name a type
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/cpp_type_traits.h:87: error: ‘__true_type’ does not name a type
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/cpp_type_traits.h:110: error: ‘__true_type’ does not name a type
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/cpp_type_traits.h:125: error: ‘__true_type’ does not name a type
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/cpp_type_traits.h:145: error: ‘__true_type’ does not name a type
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/cpp_type_traits.h:152: error: ‘__true_type’ does not name a type
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/cpp_type_traits.h:159: error: ‘__true_type’ does not name a type
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/cpp_type_traits.h:166: error: ‘__true_type’ does not name a type
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/cpp_type_traits.h:198: error: ‘__true_type’ does not name a type
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/cpp_type_traits.h:205: error: ‘__true_type’ does not name a type
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/cpp_type_traits.h:212: error: ‘__true_type’ does not name a type
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/cpp_type_traits.h:219: error: ‘__true_type’ does not name a type
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/cpp_type_traits.h:226: error: ‘__true_type’ does not name a type
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/cpp_type_traits.h:233: error: ‘__true_type’ does not name a type
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/cpp_type_traits.h:240: error: ‘__true_type’ does not name a type
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/cpp_type_traits.h:247: error: ‘__true_type’ does not name a type
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/cpp_type_traits.h:265: error: ‘__true_type’ does not name a type
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/cpp_type_traits.h:272: error: ‘__true_type’ does not name a type
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/cpp_type_traits.h:279: error: ‘__true_type’ does not name a type
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/cpp_type_traits.h:296: error: ‘__true_type’ does not name a type
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/cpp_type_traits.h:310: error: ‘__gnu_cxx’ was not declared in this scope
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/cpp_type_traits.h:311: error: template argument 1 is invalid
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/cpp_type_traits.h:355: error: ‘__true_type’ does not name a type
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/cpp_type_traits.h:378: error: ‘__true_type’ does not name a type
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/cpp_type_traits.h:385: error: ‘__true_type’ does not name a type
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/cpp_type_traits.h:392: error: ‘__true_type’ does not name a type
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/cpp_type_traits.h:417: error: ‘_GLIBCXX_END_NAMESPACE’ does not name a type
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/cmath:45,
                 from ../inst/include/Rcpp/platform/compiler.h:100,
                 from ../inst/include/Rcpp/r/headers.h:48,
                 from ../inst/include/RcppCommon.h:29,
                 from ../inst/include/Rcpp.h:27,
                 from Date.cpp:31:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/ext/type_traits.h:45: error: ‘__enable_if’ is not a template
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/ext/type_traits.h:64: error: ‘__is_integer’ is not a member of ‘std’
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/ext/type_traits.h:64: error: ‘__is_integer’ is not a member of ‘std’
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/ext/type_traits.h:64: error: template argument 1 is invalid
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/ext/type_traits.h:64: error: typedef name may not be a nested-name-specifier
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/ext/type_traits.h:64: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘>’ token
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/ext/type_traits.h:67: error: ‘__if_type’ has not been declared
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/ext/type_traits.h:107: error: ‘__is_integer’ is not a member of ‘std’
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/ext/type_traits.h:107: error: ‘__is_integer’ is not a member of ‘std’
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/ext/type_traits.h:107: error: template argument 1 is invalid
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/ext/type_traits.h:107: error: typedef name may not be a nested-name-specifier
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/ext/type_traits.h:107: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘>’ token
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/ext/type_traits.h:110: error: ‘__if_type’ has not been declared
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/ext/type_traits.h:158: error: ‘__is_integer’ is not a member of ‘std’
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/ext/type_traits.h:158: error: expected primary-expression before ‘>’ token
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/ext/type_traits.h:158: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘>’ token
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/ext/type_traits.h:163: error: ‘__promote’ is not a template
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/cmath:46,
                 from ../inst/include/Rcpp/platform/compiler.h:100,
                 from ../inst/include/Rcpp/r/headers.h:48,
                 from ../inst/include/RcppCommon.h:29,
                 from ../inst/include/Rcpp.h:27,
                 from Date.cpp:31:
/usr/include/math.h:30: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘extern’
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/ios:40,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/ostream:40,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/iterator:65,
                 from ../inst/include/RcppCommon.h:49,
                 from ../inst/include/Rcpp.h:27,
                 from Date.cpp:31:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/exception:35: error: expected declaration before end of line
make: *** [Date.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘Rcpp’
* removing ‘/usr/lib64/R/library/Rcpp’
```

### Other Things I've Tried

- Verified that `gcc.x86_64`, `gcc-c++.x86_64`, and `gcc-gfortran.x86_64` are installed
- Verified that `make` and `automake` are installed

Comment: You may need to upgrade your compiler; unfortunately CentOS 6 ships with a fairly dated version of gcc. [This](http://ask.xmodulo.com/upgrade-gcc-centos.html) may be helpful.

Comment: @nrussell It was definitely worth a shot but unfortunately that didn't do the trick, still seeing the same error even with that SCL enabled.

Comment: @nrussell So that was a rookie move on my part. You were right, using the SCL did in fact fix the issue. When I'd initially switched to the SCL with `scl enable devtoolset-1.1 bash` I did so as myself but that didn't carry over when I sudoed to install.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in the [comments above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33174490/trouble-compiling-rcpp?noredirect=1#comment54156563_33174490) the trick was using a new version of the compiler via an SCL.

The steps below are adapted from this page on [Ask Xmodulo](http://ask.xmodulo.com/upgrade-gcc-centos.html).

```
$ sudo wget http://people.centos.org/tru/devtools-1.1/devtools-1.1.repo -P /etc/yum.repos.d
$ sudo sh -c 'echo "enabled=1" >> /etc/yum.repos.d/devtools-1.1.repo'
```

On RHEL6 ayou may need to update the .repo file that got installed to manually set the baseurl to `http://people.centos.org/tru/devtools-1.1/6/$basearch/RPMS`. From there:

```
$ sudo yum install devtoolset-1.1
```

To install system wide R libraries you need to run it as root so doing `scl enable devtoolset-1.1 bash` and then running `sudo R` will run the application but without the SCL enabled. So instead:

```
$ sudo scl enable devtoolset-1.1 bash
```

That will start a bash shell as root with the SCL enabled. Finally you can install the library with:

```
# R CMD INSTALL Rcpp_0.12.1.tar.gz
```